# add text area to GridPane in javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx, textarea

when i try to add a textArea to a grid pane it says that the method add can add only nodes, not TextArea. What can I do?

Here is what I have tried:

```
        GridPane expContent = new GridPane();
        expContent.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        expContent.add(ta, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import JavaFX's TextArea:

```
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
```

and remove the wrong import.

Comment: @spoke wait. NPE is a different error from the one in the question. So it seems you resolved syntax errors and now you are facing a runtime error. In this case, check the error message. There you will find the line number at where the error is occurred. Determine the cause and fix it. If still having trouble feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: the error appears here: gridpane.add(textArea, 0, 1);

Comment: to use textArea I have to declare it static, but then I receive NPE. any suggestion? And I can't declare it locally because a add text to it from different classes

Comment: How did you instantiate the textarea? Show the code.

Comment: managed to solve the problem eventually. Thank you for your help!